# need to access directory list in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I need to create a folder and files in this path 
`/var/mobile/Containers/Data/`
but when I look for it can't find the folder 
my code >>

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDownloadsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = @"/var/mobile/Containers";//[paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyNewFolder/myDB.db"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: iOS apps are sandboxed...

Comment: need to create public db to access it from multi apps can make it ??

Comment: @ya this is really, really basic iOS stuff, the type that covered in any tutorial when you just start getting into it. I suggest searching the Net. There are tons of resources out there.

Answer (score 0):

**I dint really understood your problem . Hope this helps :**

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [paths  objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"Saving");

        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];

        NSString *path1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/var/mobile/Containers"];

        NSString *dataPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:path1];

        dataPath = [dataPath stringByStandardizingPath];

                filePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyNewFolder/myDB.db"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the iOS 8 approach [Apple recommends to retrieve the location of the Documents directory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html):

```
// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ## Create Folder

```
  //-- to select path from image--//
    AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSString *dataPath=[del.databasePath copy];
    NSString *Documentpath=[del.path_Folder_Document copy];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Fetch path for document directory
    dataPath = (NSMutableString *)[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Images"];
    Pathforimage=dataPath;
```

> ## Add Folder if not Exist

```
 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:Pathforimage withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil])
    {
        //NSLog(@"directory... /Images already exist..");
    }
    else
    {
        //NSLog(@"directory created!");
    }
    NSString *pathforAudios=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Images_Audio",Documentpath];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:pathforAudios withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil])
    {
        //NSLog(@"directory... /Images already exist..");
    }
    else
    {
        //NSLog(@"directory created!");
    }

    //-- end of  path --//
```

> ## Save Image to Folder

```
   //Save Image to Documents Directory
   NSString  *imagePath = [Pathforimage stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",Img_File_Name]];
   [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
   imagePath=nil;
   image=nil;
```

> ## Delete Files/Folder

```
  NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *files = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    NSLog(@"files =%@",files);

     NSString *Images_Folder = (NSMutableString *)[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Images"];
NSArray *fileArray = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:Images_Folder error:nil];
for (NSString *filename in fileArray)
{
    NSLog(@"Images =%@",filename);
    [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:[Images_Folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];
}

NSString *Images_Audio_Folder = (NSMutableString *)[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Images_Audio"];
NSArray *fileArray1 = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:Images_Audio_Folder error:nil];
for (NSString *filename in fileArray1)
{
    NSLog(@"Images_Audio =%@",filename);
    [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:[Images_Audio_Folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];
}
```

Comment: @Yahia El-Dow, Here is the Perfect SOlution

Comment: this code create file in same project folder but i need create folder outside application folder

Comment: its not possible my friend

Comment: u can't access Other than Document Directory.

Comment: can create public Data Base and access it from multi apps or can`t

Comment: u cant Access Other App Sandbox

Comment: @YahiaEl-Dow, please upvote answer, if u got any necessory information related to Question.

Answer (score 0):

**Create floder**

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyNewFolder"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]){
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

}else{
   NSLog(@"exist");
}
NSLog(@"dataPath:%@",dataPath);
```